# Move, Scale and Rotate ImageView OnTouch not working

Tags: android, rotation, multi-touch

i have days trying to make this work, checked out some other answers and none seem to work for me :S

i add a sticker to a RelativeLayout, i want the sticker to Move, Scale and Rotate with OnTouch Methods once it is selected (it has an OnClickListener that calls a setOnTouchListener)
keeping in mind that i can have N stickers added.

```
private void addSticker(ImageView sticker)
{

    flMemeFrame.addView(sticker);

    sticker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            {
                if (selectedView != null)
                {
                    CancelSelection(selectedView);
                }
                selectedView = v;

                v.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
                {
                    private float mScaleFactor = 0.5f;
                    private float mRotationDegree = 0.f;
                    private float mFocusX = 0.f;
                    private float mFocusY = 0.f;
                    private int mScreenHeight;
                    private int mScreenWidth;
                    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();//Các lớp Matrix giữ một ma trận 3x3 để di chuyển tọa độ.
                    private int mImageWidth, mImageHeight;
                    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
                    private RotateGestureDetector mRotateDetector;
                    private MoveGestureDetector mMoveDetector;

                    class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
                            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 1.0f));
                            return true;
                        }
                    }

                    class RotateListener extends RotateGestureDetector.SimpleOnRotateGestureListener {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onRotate(RotateGestureDetector detector) {
                            mRotationDegree -= detector.getRotationDegreesDelta();
                            return true;
                        }
                    }

                    class MoveListener extends MoveGestureDetector.SimpleOnMoveGestureListener {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMove(MoveGestureDetector detector) {
                            PointF d = detector.getFocusDelta();
                            mFocusX += d.x;
                            mFocusY += d.y;

                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
                    {
                        mImageHeight = v.getHeight();
                        mImageWidth = v.getWidth();

                        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
                        mRotateDetector = new RotateGestureDetector(context, new RotateListener());
                        mMoveDetector = new MoveGestureDetector(context, new MoveListener());

                        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                        mRotateDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                        mMoveDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                        float scaleImageCenterX = (mImageWidth * mScaleFactor) / 2;
                        float scaleImageCenterY = (mImageHeight * mScaleFactor) / 2;

                        matrix.reset();
                        matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
                        matrix.postRotate(mRotationDegree, scaleImageCenterX, scaleImageCenterY);
                        matrix.postTranslate(mFocusX - scaleImageCenterX, mFocusY - scaleImageCenterY);

                        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
                        view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
                        view.setImageMatrix(matrix);

                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

here is where i set the image

```
ImageView sticker = new ImageView(context);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
                sticker.setLayoutParams(rlp);
addSticker(sticker);
```

the app compiles and no crashes, but the sticker does NOTHING OnTouch :(

links that i have tried:

http://code.almeros.com/android-multitouch-gesture-detectors#.V1Y0sZMrLMW

[rotation and scaling and move using multi touch in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690572/rotation-and-scaling-and-move-using-multi-touch-in-android)

and some other links that i can't find now

anyone that can help?

EDIT: the code for CancelSelection (completely unrelated, as the only thing i'm doing is setting selectedView as null and removing the background, i also remove the OnTouchListener, because i don't want to move/scale/rotate the view if it's not selected)

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void CancelSelection(View v)
{
    if(isCaptionEditPanelOpen)
    {
        rlQuickEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        rlQuickEdit = null;
        isCaptionEditPanelOpen = false;
    }
    //toogleButtonVisibility(false);
    v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    selectedView = null;
    v.setOnTouchListener(null);
}
```

i wrote this class, to see if i can make it work without all the complexity of my app, same results:

```
package com.andujardev.imagerotation;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    Context context;
    ImageView imgRotate;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;

        imgRotate = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgRotate);

        imgRotate.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {
            private float mScaleFactor = 0.5f;
            private float mRotationDegree = 0.f;
            private float mFocusX = 0.f;
            private float mFocusY = 0.f;
            private int mScreenHeight;
            private int mScreenWidth;
            private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            private int mImageWidth, mImageHeight;
            private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
            private RotateGestureDetector mRotateDetector;
            private MoveGestureDetector mMoveDetector;

            class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
                @Override
                public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                    mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
                    mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 1.0f));
                    return true;
                }
            }

            class RotateListener extends RotateGestureDetector.SimpleOnRotateGestureListener {
                @Override
                public boolean onRotate(RotateGestureDetector detector) {
                    mRotationDegree -= detector.getRotationDegreesDelta();
                    return true;
                }
            }

            class MoveListener extends MoveGestureDetector.SimpleOnMoveGestureListener {
                @Override
                public boolean onMove(MoveGestureDetector detector) {
                    PointF d = detector.getFocusDelta();
                    mFocusX += d.x;
                    mFocusY += d.y;

                    return true;
                }
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                mImageHeight = v.getHeight();
                mImageWidth = v.getWidth();

                mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
                mRotateDetector = new RotateGestureDetector(context, new RotateListener());
                mMoveDetector = new MoveGestureDetector(context, new MoveListener());

                mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                mRotateDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                mMoveDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                float scaleImageCenterX = (mImageWidth * mScaleFactor) / 2;
                float scaleImageCenterY = (mImageHeight * mScaleFactor) / 2;

                matrix.reset();
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
                matrix.postRotate(mRotationDegree, scaleImageCenterX, scaleImageCenterY);
                matrix.postTranslate(mFocusX - scaleImageCenterX, mFocusY - scaleImageCenterY);

                ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
                view.setImageMatrix(matrix);

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, your don't understand work of gesture. Answer below is correct with your code above, because using touch, it's not the same as click. Read more about all gesture in Google Doc.

Comment: It is not wrong, i just ENABLE gestures on a specific item when the user selected it using a ClickListener, when the TouchListener Is Active, the Click Listener is not called, when the user clicks OUTSIDE the item, the image gets unselected and you cant use gestures on it

Comment: Another important thing here is that i created another project, used the Gestures code (without all the complexity of my app) and it doesn't work either...

Answer (score 2):

It's interesting that for *every* `onTouch` event you instantiate a new `ScaleGestureDetector`, `RotateGestureDetector`, and `MoveGestureDetector`.

Considering *each* respective gesture detector needs the previous touch event to determine and interpret how to react this is decidedly a significant part of your issue since you create a new gesture detector for each touch event.  In fact if you look in the source for the `Almeros` detector for the `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)` method it states:

```
Applications should pass a complete and consistent event stream to this method.
* A complete and consistent event stream involves all MotionEvents from the initial
* ACTION_DOWN to the final ACTION_UP or ACTION_CANCEL.
```

For starters you should ensure that you are only creating a *single* detector object so it can consume all touch events.

Comment: i already found the solution, this was one of the problems but i was lacking a good explanation, thanks!! the other problem was that the image was set to WRAP_CONTENT, and this code does not move/scale/rotate the ImageView but the Drawable in the imageView , so the ImageView must be MATCH_PARENT, and that leads me to a bigger problem. i can only edit the LAST added image...(It takes the ImageView as the Matrix so scales and rotates IN that matrix, i want the matrix to be my FrameLayout but i don't know how to change this)

Comment: well, the bounty period has ended, and so far you were the only one who hit one of the points, so i will award the bounty to you, however, my problem is not exactly (or completely) solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ..the reason the above code doesnt work is because the TouchListener and ClickListener cannot work together in the above situation..Click requires that you touch and then leave the View for the Event to occur.However the Touch event requires that you are still touching the View...

```
private void addSticker(ImageView sticker)
{

flMemeFrame.addView(sticker);

sticker.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
            {
                private float mScaleFactor = 0.5f;
                private float mRotationDegree = 0.f;
                private float mFocusX = 0.f;
                private float mFocusY = 0.f;
                private int mScreenHeight;
                private int mScreenWidth;
                private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();//Các lớp Matrix giữ một ma trận 3x3 để di chuyển tọa độ.
                private int mImageWidth, mImageHeight;
                private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
                private RotateGestureDetector mRotateDetector;
                private MoveGestureDetector mMoveDetector;

                class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
                        mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 1.0f));
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                class RotateListener extends RotateGestureDetector.SimpleOnRotateGestureListener {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onRotate(RotateGestureDetector detector) {
                        mRotationDegree -= detector.getRotationDegreesDelta();
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                class MoveListener extends MoveGestureDetector.SimpleOnMoveGestureListener {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMove(MoveGestureDetector detector) {
                        PointF d = detector.getFocusDelta();
                        mFocusX += d.x;
                        mFocusY += d.y;

                        return true;
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
                {
                    mImageHeight = v.getHeight();
                    mImageWidth = v.getWidth();

                    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
                    mRotateDetector = new RotateGestureDetector(context, new RotateListener());
                    mMoveDetector = new MoveGestureDetector(context, new MoveListener());

                    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                    mRotateDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                    mMoveDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                    float scaleImageCenterX = (mImageWidth * mScaleFactor) / 2;
                    float scaleImageCenterY = (mImageHeight * mScaleFactor) / 2;

                    matrix.reset();
                    matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
                    matrix.postRotate(mRotationDegree, scaleImageCenterX, scaleImageCenterY);
                    matrix.postTranslate(mFocusX - scaleImageCenterX, mFocusY - scaleImageCenterY);

                    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
                    view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
                    view.setImageMatrix(matrix);

                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: you could listen for DOWN and UP Touch Events to handle the DRAG effect you want ..

Comment: the reason i'm doing that is that i actually activate the touch functions when i click on the image, as if i SELECT the image first, then i start manipulating it, when i leave the selection, then return to normal click functions.

Comment: any news on this?? :S

Comment: i am stuck ...i dont have all the classes and code u have used...RotateGestureDetector and MoveGestureDetector is missing...first i thought it was a problem because ur using the touch and click listener together...but now i feel the problem is much deeper...could you share all the code..

Comment: that class is on the first link i posted, (code.almeros.com)