# How to rotate a System Overlay Button

Tags: android, system, overlay

I have found this code on the internet and it works.

It creates a system overlay button and I can move it around the screen.

How can I do it, that this button should now be able to rotate?

Perhaps as a two finger rotation.

```
Package de.mobilej.overlay;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class OverlayShowingService extends Service implements OnTouchListener, OnClickListener {
private View topLeftView;

private Button overlayedButton;
private float offsetX;
private float offsetY;
private int originalXPos;
private int originalYPos;
private boolean moving;
private WindowManager wm;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    overlayedButton = new Button(this);
    overlayedButton.setText("TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST");
    overlayedButton.setOnTouchListener(this);
    overlayedButton.setBackgroundColor(0x55fe4444);
    overlayedButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 0;
    wm.addView(overlayedButton, params);

    topLeftView = new View(this);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams topLeftParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    topLeftParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
    topLeftParams.x = 0;
    topLeftParams.y = 0;
    topLeftParams.width = 10;
    topLeftParams.height = 10;
    wm.addView(topLeftView, topLeftParams);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (overlayedButton != null) {
        wm.removeView(overlayedButton);
        wm.removeView(topLeftView);
        overlayedButton = null;
        topLeftView = null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        float x = event.getRawX();
        float y = event.getRawY();

        moving = false;
        int[] location = new int[2];
        overlayedButton.getLocationOnScreen(location);

        originalXPos = location[0];
        originalYPos = location[1];

        offsetX = originalXPos - x;
        offsetY = originalYPos - y;

    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        int[] topLeftLocationOnScreen = new int[2];
        topLeftView.getLocationOnScreen(topLeftLocationOnScreen);
        System.out.println("topLeftY="+topLeftLocationOnScreen[1]);
        System.out.println("originalY="+originalYPos);

        float x = event.getRawX();
        float y = event.getRawY();
       WindowManager.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) overlayedButton.getLayoutParams();

        int newX = (int) (offsetX + x);
        int newY = (int) (offsetY + y);

        if (Math.abs(newX - originalXPos) < 1 && Math.abs(newY - originalYPos) < 1 && !moving) {
            return false;
        }

        params.x = newX - (topLeftLocationOnScreen[0]);
        params.y = newY - (topLeftLocationOnScreen[1]);
        wm.updateViewLayout(overlayedButton, params);
        moving = true;
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (moving) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Overlay button click event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}}
```

Comment: The code you have posted isn't really relevant to your question and you don't seem to have made any attempt to solve this yourself.  People on Stack Overflow don't write code for you, they help you to fix yours.

Comment: @Tibrogargan the code is extremely relevant to the question of how to rotate a system overlay item using touch. Stack Overflow is for asking questions that can be answered with something as simple as where to start or where to get more information. Don't make it a hostile environment.

Answer (score 0):

Rotating a system overlay is no different than rotating a view. You would start by intercepting the touch and then translate that into view rotation.

To achieve a two finger touch rotation, you would want to get the magnitude of the movement, then translate it to the number of degrees that should rotate the view.

Once you have the degrees of rotation, you would apply that to the layout.

There is a decent question on rotating a view using multitouch at [rotation and scaling and move using multi touch in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690572/rotation-and-scaling-and-move-using-multi-touch-in-android)